# Insert,delete,update product should reflect in third party website using API

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, api

I have a website which sells clothing and selling in elevenia. Elevenia have a seller option where we can add or create our product in the dashboard.

Its a tedious process and we go for Open API services which is provided by elevenia. Using API when we add,delete,update product in magento backend it should reflect in elevenia. API is provided by elevenia.

Basically, the format should be .xml and magento supports this feature. I don't have customer support from elevenia. Can anyone please tell me how to integrate third party API with magento? We have API key and tested with POSTMAN app using GET and POST method. I can get the values and can add the product.

The thing is how can I do it in magento? Please help me